# Can't understand C program output

Tags: c

I was making some basic programs and i made this program

```
 #include<stdio.>
 int main()
 {
   printf("%d\n",-1>>4);
   return 0;
 }
```

output = -1

i could not understand how it happens ?

is -1 is 2's complemented first and then shift operation is done .and then again 2's complement is done to produce the result.

i also want to know how this output comes

```
int main()
{
 unsigned int a=4;
 printf("%d\n",-a>>4);
 return 0;   
}
```

result = 268435455

Comment: Try printing using **`%x`** and read about **arithmetic shifting**... you will understand the behavior.

Comment: `-1` is not "2's complemented". All integers and longs are stored in 2's complement to begin with, and kept that way.

Comment: @SJuan76: All signed integers are stored with the implemenations choice of signed representation: Sign-and-Magnitude, 2s-complement, 1s-complement.

Comment: Try not to mix signed integers and bitwise operations: `printf("%u\n", -1U >> 4);`

Comment: Bitwise operations on signed values are messy enough when both 2s-complement and arithmetic shift are guaranteed.

Comment: so here -1 is taken as signed integer? if i take as unsigned and then negate it , will i get same result?

Comment: @MadHatter Passing an `int` to `printf("%x",…)` is technically undefined behavior.

Comment: @PascalCuoq : That is like an update for me. Can you please point me to proper link/text supporting this.

Comment: @MadHatter C11 7.21.6.1:8 “o,u,x,X The **unsigned int** argument is …”. 7.21.6.1:9 “[…] If any argument is not the correct type for the corresponding conversion specification, the behavior is undefined.” http://open-std.org/jtc1/sc22/wg14/www/docs/n1570.pdf

Comment: so if i print an unsigned value using %d , the behaviour is undefined..??

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For a start, what you're doing is non-portable.

ISO C11 states, in `6.5.7 Bitwise shift operators`:

> The result of E1 >> E2 is E1 right-shifted E2 bit positions. If E1 has an unsigned type
>   or if E1 has a signed type and a nonnegative value, the value of the result is the integral
>   part of the quotient of E1 / 2^E2 . **If E1 has a signed type and a negative value, the
>   resulting value is implementation-defined.**

So it's not wise to do that.

What's possibly happening is that you have an implementation that preserves sign on the negative values. Whereas `>>` may normally shift in zero bits on the left hand side (and *must* do so for an unsigned or signed-nonnegative value), your implementation could detect a negative number and shifts in one-bits into the second-from-left position, leaving the left bit untouched.

That means `-1` (eg: binary `1111 1111 1111 1111`) will *still* have that bit pattern after a right-shift.

You would have to examine the documentation for your particular implementation to be sure (Appendix J of the standard requires implementations to document their choices for implementation-defined behaviours).

You could also test it with a few better sample values like binary `1100 0000 0000 0000` right-shifted by one bit, and see what comes out (though, of course, the implementation notes should be the definitive source).

---

By way of example, the `gcc` documentation provides this information [here](http://gcc.gnu.org/onlinedocs/). Since you mention you're using 4.6.3, the 4.6.4 manuals are probably the closest.

The `GCC 4.6.4 Manual (also in PDF or PostScript or an HTML tarball)` link on that page contains a section entitled `C implementation-defined behaviour` which states, in part:

> **The results of some bitwise operations on signed integers (C90 6.3, C99 6.5).**
>
> Bitwise operators act on the representation of the value including both the sign and
>   value bits, where the sign bit is considered immediately above the highest-value value
>   bit. Signed ‘>>’ acts on negative numbers by sign extension.

That means it acts as I explained, with the left bit staying put *and* affecting the second-most left bit:

[image]

---

The reason why you're seeing a different value with:

```
unsigned int a=4;
printf("%d\n",-a>>4);
```

is because `-a` is, for some reason I'm not entirely certain of, being treated as the unsigned representation of -4. You can see that with:

```
#include <stdio.h>
int main()
{
    unsigned int a=4;
    printf("%09x\n",((unsigned int)(-a))>>1);
    printf("%09x\n",(-a)>>1);
    printf("%09x\n",(-((int)a))>>1);
    return 0;
}
```

which outputs (annotated):

```
07ffffffe  # explicit unsigned int
07ffffffe  # seemingly treated as unsigned int

0fffffffe  # explicit int
```

I *suspect* this has to do with integer promotions and the usual arithmetic conversions detailed in ISO C11 `6.5 Expressions` but I think that's moving well beyond the scope of the original question.

Comment: Add disclaimer about 2s-complement being assumed?

Comment: Has anybody seen an implementation that would do anything else in last 20 years?

Comment: i also wanted to know where it can differ, if its implementation specific.

Comment: @mrigendra, it can differ in any manner. The implementation-defined section of ISO C states: `A conforming implementation is required to document its choice of behavior in each of the areas listed in this subclause`. The standard doesn't mandate _what_ behaviours are possible here (in 6.5), only that the implementation must document it.

Comment: how this works unsigned int a = 4;  printf("%d",-a>>4);  result = 268435455

Comment: Perhaps I haven't stressed this enough - it works the way your implementation _states_ that it works. There is no hard and fast rule imposed by the standard. Your implementation is probably well within its rights to always give you `42` if it so wishes, provided it documents the fact.

Comment: i have gcc version 4.6.3 .you mean i need to read the whole documentation first to expect it to do what i want..

Comment: @mrigendra, no you don't have to read _all_ the doco, just the bit of implementation-defined behaviour. See the update.

Answer (score 2):

-1 has the binary representation (assuming 2's complement):

```
11111111111111111111111111111111       // All ones, 32 of them if we assume 32 bit ints
```

When right-shifting signed numbers, your compiler seems to shift in 1 if the sign bit is 1.

```
11111111111111111111111111111111       // All ones, 32 of them if we assume 32 bit ints
^^^^ These 4 are new
```

As you can see, the number stays the same, -1.

Answer (score 0):

-1 is  FFFFFFFF in bits, so when you right shift by any bits it will still be FFFFFFFF which is -1

Comment: It depends. A logical right shift will be `7FFFFFFF` (`MAX_INT`).